# Make 2 lines appear as table

Tags: ms-word, ms-office, excel-2016, office-2016, word-2016

I have a list like this

```
Id Number
Name
```

i.e.,

```
101g
aaa
102g
bbb
103g
ccc
```

etc.,

I need them to appear in single line

```
Id Number Name
101g      aaa
102g      bbb
103g      ccc
```

How to do this?
Can anyone help pls?

Answer (score 0):

In Excel, assuming your data is in column A, enter the following formula in any other column

```
=INDEX($A:$A,(ROW(1:1))*2-1)
```

In the column next to this, enter the following,

```
=INDEX($A:$A,(ROW(1:1))*2)
```

Now copy both of these down.